# Pre-compiled css un-findable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

im trying to add my css to my layout and im having an issue of rails not being able to find it.

The Error

```
Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( index.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

The Code

```
<head>
<title>Site</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'home', media: 'all' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'home/index' if params[:action] == 'index' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

The weird part is that i can access the index css file from 'localhost:3000/assets/home/index.css'

The precompiled assets

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets", "commons")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets", "home")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets", "access")

config.assets.precompile += ['home.css', 'access.css']
config.assets.precompile += ['home/index.css', 'access/login.css', 'access/register.css']
config.assets.precompile += ['access.js']
```

Comment: Are you in production or development environment?

Comment: Development Enviroment

Comment: try to remove extension from precompile command. I.e. "home/index" instead of "home/index.css"

Comment: No sorry that didnt work, it does work if i change it to "index.css" isntead of "home/index.css" which is weird.

Comment: It's because you add your home directory to assets paths. Just remove third line and it should work with home/index

Comment: Could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: There is a list of assets paths. You can watch it if type `y Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in you rails console. 
It parses all subfolders of these paths and you can reference files with relative path from these folders. So, by default it adds assets/stylesheets/home/index.css in assets as this file is in subfolder of stylesheets and you can reference it as "home/index.css"

Comment: When you set `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets", "home")` it cosiders home as separate assets folder and now you should reference "assets/stylesheets/home/index.css" just as index.css

Comment: But it currently works well for the access css

Comment: Found the bug, the home/index.css file was a .scss file which would generally work find but after changing the home/index.css file to a .css file everything worked fine.